# TcpNioClientConnectionFactory vs TcpNetClientConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration

I am using :

- spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.3.RELEASE
- spring-integration-ip-4.3.19.RELEASE
- spring-integration-http-4.3.19.RELEASE

I want to know what is the difference between these two implementations TcpNetClientConnectionFactory and TcpNioClientConnectionFactory.

I have created a application for connect to a server and my application must support a high volumen of transaction per seconds maybe 100 transactions per seconds.

I don't know if my implementation is correct for support a high volumen or not.

The NIO implementation usually is recommend to avoid blocking, but I don't know if it changes the type of implementation my application will improves.

```
public IntegrationFlow createTcpConnection(String connectionId, String host, int port, int headBytes,
        int retryInterval) 
{

    LOGGER.debug("createTcpConnection ->  connectionId: {} - host: {} - port: {} - headBytes: {} - retryInterval: {}"
            ,connectionId,host,port,headBytes,retryInterval);
    IntegrationFlow ifr = existsConnection(connectionId);
    if (ifr == null) {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        final ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer by = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(headBytes);
        cf.setSingleUse(false);
        cf.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        cf.setSerializer(by);
        cf.setDeserializer(by);
        cf.setComponentName(connectionId);

        //Inbound Adapter 
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        adapter.setClientMode(true);
        adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
        adapter.setRetryInterval(retryInterval);

        ifr = IntegrationFlows
                .from(adapter)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("connectionId",connectionId))
                .channel(fromTcp)
                .handle("BridgeMessageEndpoint", "outbound")
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(ifr).id(connectionId+CONNECTION_SUFFIX + ".in").addBean(cf).register();



        //OutBound Adapter
        TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        sender.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(sender);
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(connectionId+CONNECTION_SUFFIX + ".out").register();

           LOGGER.debug("createTcpConnection: Connection created");
    }
    return ifr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, from an I/O perspective, `TcpNet*` will be more efficient for a small/medium number of long-lived connections. `TcpNio*` would be better for a large number of connections and/or very short-lived connections.

If you want to process inbound messages in parallel with a `TcpNet...` configuration, you can use an executor channel as the adapter's output channel so the IO thread hands off the work to another thread.

Comment: One more diff - Only TCPNio supports disabling sslVerifyHost. @Gary Russell why it is designed this way?

Comment: Don't ask the same question in multiple places, it's a waste of your time and ours; as I answered on Gitter, use `cf.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(false));` for `TcpNet*`.